# How to insert numpy arrays of size 1 into an empty numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, artificial-intelligence

I am defining two NumPy arrays:

```
PREtrain_labels = np.asarray([inpLblsArray[0:80]])
train_labels = np.array([])
TRstore = 0
i = 0

while i < len(train_images):
  TRstore = np.asarray([PREtrain_labels.item(i)])
  np.append(train_labels, TRstore)
  i = i + 1
```

Here, I have a NumPy array `PREtrain_labels` which contains integers and was sliced from a larger NumPy array. I defined an empty array `train_labels`. My goal is to fill the empty NumPy array (`train_labels`) with the selected slice of integers in the array `PREtrain_labels`. But there is a catch, as I take each integer from the `PREtrain_labels` array, I want each integer to be placed inside another empty array which is called `TRstore`. Then, I want to take the `TRstore` NumPy array and place it inside the empty `train_labels` array. However, when I run the code and print the final `train_labels` array, it is empty.

How can possibly fix this? If `np.append()` is the wrong method to use, which one should I use? The code above will not run alone, so, I am simplifying my code below into a runnable version. Thanks in advance!

```
loopArr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
target = np.array([])
store = 0
i = 0

while i < len(loopArr):
  store = np.asarray([a.item(i)])
  np.append(target, store)
  i = i + 1

print(target)
```

Comment: np.append is not a list append clone!  Don't use it!

Comment: You can't put anything inside an array like your initial `train_labels`.  It is shape (0,) and float dtype.  And making a new array by concatenating something with it is inefficient.  Stick with list append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [30]: res = np.array([])                                                                    
In [31]: np.append(res, np.array(1))                                                           
Out[31]: array([1.])
In [32]: res                                                                                   
Out[32]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`Out[31}` is a 1 element float array - because `res` is float.  But note that `res` has not changed.  `np.append` is a just badly conceived 'cover' for `np.concatenate`.

`concatenate` is a bit pickier about the dimensions of the inputs

```
In [33]: np.concatenate([ res, np.array(1)])                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-bb45ea1930d0> in <module>
----> 1 np.concatenate([ res, np.array(1)])

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
In [34]: np.concatenate([ res, np.array([1])])                                                 
Out[34]: array([1.])
```

This joins one (0,) shape array with a (1,) shape to produce a (1,).  That `[]` array is nearly useless.

`concatenate` takes a whole list of arrays (or even lists).  Take advantage of that:

```
In [35]: np.concatenate([np.array([1]), np.array([2]), [3], [1,2,3]])                          
Out[35]: array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
```

But why are you doing `append` in a loop?  Why not list appends?  That works in-place and is relatively fast and error free.  Why make life hard for yourself?

Comment: I am trying to input labels into a CNN which requires numpy arrays as input. I tried lists which did not work. However, your solution fixes my problem, thanks!